# open relative path when imported from another directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

say I have a file structure like

```
a
    __init__.py
    a.py
    a.txt
b.py
```

Now, say `a/a.py` looks something like:

```
print open("a.txt").read()
```

and maybe `b.py` says:

```
from a import a
```

I'm experiencing some issues with similar code.
I run `b.py`, which seems to be looking for `a.txt` relative to itself, not relative to `a.py`. How can I solve this if I want `a.py` to work independently as well as when imported from another directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open `a.txt` with its absolute path. Edit `a.py` like this:

```
import os
base = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(base, 'a.txt')
print open(path).read()
```

When you call `open('a.txt')`, the python interpreter will look in the current working directory, which is usually where you invoked the interpreter.

Calling `os.path.abspatch(__file__)` will get you the absolute path of the current file, in your case `a.py`. Wrapping that in `os.path.dirname()` will give you the absolute path of the directory of the current file.

Comment: will calling `os.path.abspath` on my local path from `a.py` also use the cwd?

Comment: Will anything be messed up if I simply do `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`?

Comment: I'd always try to go for absolute paths if possible, what if at some point you want to import something from `b.py` or another module but have changed the working dir?

Comment: Right. This is less convenient because I'm working with a module that has a default path if a path is not specifically specified, in addition to opening files myself. It's easier not to pass the absolute path to the module, but I suppose if it's the best practice I should.